# How do you make a circle button?

Tags: html, css, button

I am wondering how are you able to create a circle button using HTML and CSS. I feel like it has something to do with border-radius after you set a proper width and height but it didnt work out like I hoped. The image below shows what it should look like.
[What the button should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhXjX.png)

Comment: show us what have you tried so far. Without looking at your code it is hard to point out where you're doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

For a circle shaped button all you need to do is set your `border-radius` to `50%`. Change the `background-color` of the button to `white` and you should be good to go. You can also set your `.button` `height`, `width`, `font-size` and `font-family` to mimic your desired look.

```css
<style>
.cont {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:lightgrey
;
}

.button{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius: 50%;
border:none;
background-color:lightgrey;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="cont">
<button class="button">Explore</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want a generalized solution then you can try this

**HTML**

```
<button>Explore</button>
```

**CSS**

```
    button {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: white;
    }
```

You can adjust the width & height according to your requirement